# Using _i with moment js is not working when using it in with if condition

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using `_i` in momentjs with if condition but it is not giving expected output.

Here is my code:

```
var output = "07-14-2017";
var selectedDates = "06-15-2018";

if(moment(output)._i <= moment(selectedDates)._i)
{
  console.log(output date is less than or equal selected date);
}
else
{
  console.log(output date is greater than selected date);
}
```

Here my output date is of 2017 and `selecteddates` is of 2018, still it is giving me an output of 'output date is greater than selected date'. It should give me an output 'output date is less than or equal selected date'.

I have given all jQuery and momentjs files references properly.

Comment: The actual question should be why you're using `_i` (a "private" property used to store the input value) at all? Check the documentation of [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) on how to compare two dates correctly.

Comment: In case someone needs to access the original "input" (_i) in a valid way, you can use moment.creationData()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_i returns string which is not correct and also you should not use it as per  @Andreas comments.
You can use below code gives correct comparison.

```
moment(selectedDates).isAfter(output);
```

Comment: @SanjayMakwana Can you please accept the answer :) Using tick next to the ans.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issue with your code:

1. You are trying to parse using [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) a string that is neither in RFC2822 or ISO 8601 recognized format, so your code gives *Deprecation warning*. You have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead.
2. You are using `_i` that as [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide states:

   > [...] the values of `_d` and any other properties prefixed with `_` should not be used for any purpose.

To compare moment objects you can use [`isSameOrBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/), [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/), [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) and the others methods listed in the [Query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) section of the docs.

Here a working sample:

```js
var output = "07-14-2017";
var selectedDates = "06-15-2018";

if(moment(output, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isSameOrBefore(moment(selectedDates, 'MM-DD-YYYY')))
{
  console.log("output date is less than or equal selected date");
}
else
{
  console.log("output date is greater than selected date");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What will it cost to also get three additional months per year? I think that would be awesome^^

Comment: @Andreas ahahah I agree, that would be awesome :D thank you for pointing out the error about format (I was influenced by my locale that uses `DD-MM-YYYY`). I've edited my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it works in Chrome 59, however it threw the following warning:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
>   ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
>   reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
>   formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
>   release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

It's possible that your issues are with your browser's javascript engine's implementation of Date(), as hinted in the warning above.

I would recommend you reformat your dates to a more moment-friendly format and try again.